# What values trigger the Null Coalesce Operator ?? passing in php 7?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm excited about the possibilities of the null Coalesce Operator (the ?? operator) coming out in PHP 7. However, I don't understand all of the cases.

What will my result be for the following cases?

```
function NC($x){
    $y = array();
    $y['test'] = $x;
    $returnThis = $y['test'] ?? "Foo";
    return $returnThis;
}

echo(NC(NULL)); // I know this will return "Foo".
/* But I have no clue about what these will return. */
echo(NC(0));
echo(NC(-1));
echo(NC(""));
echo(NC(array()));
```

Comment: You could install php 7 and find out

Comment: I already gave you a link to an online IDE where you can test that in your last question + Give a look into the tag wiki of php-7

Comment: Google "php 7 null coalescing operator" and you'll find a number of pages that explain how it works.

Comment: They all say that it just checks whether the left operand is null or not. `0` and `""` are not null (if you do a loose comparison they'll be equal, because it performs type conversion first, but that doesn't make them actually null).

Comment: You can always [see for yourself](https://3v4l.org/8K8Tl)

Comment: @John Conde
Solving the solution in that way doesn't get the answer on stack overflow though, which is inefficient since a lot of people search on Stack Overflow first, especially since google doesn't search operator symbols as well. Me asking this question is more for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cases:

```
NC(NULL); // This returns "foo".
NC(0); // Returns 0
NC(-1); // Returns -1
NC(""); // Returns ""
NC(array()); // Returns empty array
```

Unlike other cases that will treat certain values identical to null, the null operator doesn't. It is null, and null alone that will trigger the replacement.